# El Capitan - Login problems with SIP enabled

Tags: macos, sip

I just upgraded from Mavericks to El-Capitan. Upon attempting to log in to my profile, the login process gets stuck at the spinning load graphic, until I am forced to shut down. It appears that disabling SIP has fixed the issue, and the login took less than 5 seconds.

Why is this?

I suspect some kernel extension doing this, so I searched with `sudo kextstat | grep -v com.apple` to see the non-apple kexts. Here is a list:

```
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID <Linked Against>
  142    3 0xffffff7f83017000 0x5f000    0x5f000    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (5.0.6) FB8B8CAC-638F-3853-9CF3-5A0229B47B68 <7 5 4 3 1>
  143    0 0xffffff7f83076000 0x14000    0x14000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (6.0.1) 8FF2C637-0A5E-367E-B007-5B08655B1E8A <7 5 4 3 1>
  144    0 0xffffff7f8308a000 0x9000     0x9000     net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio (1.1.0) EEF9313A-72D9-F5C7-7408-F1F8F3E37A2C <104 5 4 3 1>
  150    0 0xffffff7f82467000 0x6000     0x6000     com.logmein.hamachi (1.0) 57549AD3-8860-C370-448E-68D7E6EBC0DA <7 5 4 1>
  152    0 0xffffff7f83093000 0x8000     0x8000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (5.0.6) 0585ED0B-8D0D-3F96-8BF9-EA50FB281D2A <151 142 41 7 5 4 3 1>
  153    0 0xffffff7f8309b000 0x5000     0x5000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (5.0.6) C5D7E667-CAFE-3B85-AE60-441006FB2BC0 <142 7 5 4 3 1>
  154    0 0xffffff7f830a0000 0x6000     0x6000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (5.0.6) 1A232B48-34B8-3B06-8963-662FD1DE7542 <142 5 4 1>
```

Comment: VirtualBox may not be compatible with El Capitan: Prerequisites on Mac OS X: 10.6.x (Snow Leopard), 10.7.x (Lion), 10.8.x (Mt. Lion), 10.9.x (Mavericks) or 10.10.x (Yosemite) running on Intel hardware. From the [build instructions page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Mac%20OS%20X%20build%20instructions).

Comment: @IconDaemon I got rid of all except telestream and intel kexts, and the login issue was gone. Either this, or it could be because of a NVRAM and SMC reset. Please post the comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox is not compatible with El Capitan. From the VirtualBox [build instructions page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Mac%20OS%20X%20build%20instructions):

> Prerequisites on Mac OS X: 10.6.x (Snow Leopard), 10.7.x (Lion),
>   10.8.x (Mt. Lion), 10.9.x (Mavericks) or 10.10.x (Yosemite) running on Intel hardware.